# Transform Input and if error raises, clean the data and re-enter it in the flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

i'm currently trying to do an ETL using SSIS in which i have as an input a flat file that i made with data like:

- Name
- Last Name
- Profession
- Range of Salary
- Email
- ID
- Phone
- Marital Status

The thing is that i'm new to SSIS, but i have some knowledge using databases. What i'm doing is that i import the data, but all the fields i have set to string. Then what i do, is that i set Data Conversion and i can convert the data to an INT which are my profession, range of salary and marital status.

But i have a problem, when one of this Integers come as a word or a letter it will fire an error, which i can handle using a script component and creating a new variable that holds to 0 in order to re-enter it to the destination flow, but i tried doing it by creating several data conversion and using a union, but it didn't work well.

I have already searched for a problem like this, but every people will write the error output to a file, what i want is to catch the error, fix it, and re-enter again to the flow in order to write it on my db.

If anyone could help me, or point me out for info that would be great.

Comment: If you are more familiar with SQL then I suggest that you import everything as string to the db and use a stored proc to transform it (including cast to int). Building fix/reimport logic in SSIS will be very compicated and error prone

Comment: Yeah it looks a bit tricky, going to look into it. Thank you

Comment: could you clarify what happened when "i tried doing it by creating several data conversion and using a union, but it didn't work well" and what did not work?

Comment: I finally got the solution by applying a data conversión individually and handling all errors in a script component.

Comment: What i did initially was that but connecting all to a single union. Now they have a union per data conversion